# How to display the default btrfs options for the current kernel (or mounted filesystem)

Tags: filesystems, btrfs, defaults

Is there any way of displaying the default btrfs options for the kernel that is currently running (or for a filesystem mounted using `defaults`)?

Answer (score 0):

`cat /proc/mounts` will show you all mounted filesystems with their currently active options.

You will find default options such as `rw,ssd,relatime` in these for instance.

It will also contain mount-specific options such as `subvolid`.